# Async loading image in the ListView in android

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am working on async load image at list view 
After searching for the tutorial , I have implement the following code:

```
    package com.example.json;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImgAdapter extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView imageView = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
        this.imageView = imageViews[0];
        return download_Image((String) imageView.getTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {

        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            URL ulrn = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ulrn.openConnection();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if (null != bmp)
                return bmp;

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I call it in my adapter, there is no execute method in the class, why is that and how to fix the problem? thanks.

```
if (entry.image_url != null) {
    thumbnail.setTag(entry.image_url);
    new ImgAdapter.execute(entry.image_url);

} else {
    thumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: `new ImgAdapter().execute(entry.image_url)` is all you want.

Comment: Thanks. But error msg : The method execute(ImageView...) in the type AsyncTask<ImageView,Void,Bitmap> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: `entry.image_url` is a string?

Comment: AsyncTask expects you to pass in ImageView array instead of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
thumbnail.setTag(entry.image_url);
new ImgAdapter().execute(thumbnail);
```

The method execute() receives the same list of arguments declared in doInBackground(). In your code, it's a list of (usually one) ImageView.

Your code is expecting the imageView to have the image's URL in its tag (as per *(String) imageView.getTag()*).

Answer (score 0):

You can call this as and make url as a Static and access it into that Asynk function
and call u r Image updater as

new ImgAdapter().execute();